# CSS - Edit a responsive form with 2 textboxs with the same width

Tags: html, css, fonts, responsive-design, textbox

I am trying to edit a form in a template. The form will be a very common search form with two textboxs (`What` and `Where`) and the button `Search`.

The two textboxs should have the same `width` and separated with a vertical grey line.

I put in the following lines the `entire code` related to the form, anyway for completeness i provide also the link of the template:

https://demo.themeregion.com/jobs-updated/details.html

This is the code of the **form**:

```
<form action="#">
                    <!-- category-change -->
                    <div class="dropdown category-dropdown">                        
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="change-text">Job Category</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu category-change">
                            <li><a href="#">Customer Service</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Software Engineer</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Program Development</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Project Manager</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Graphics Designer</a></li>
                        </ul>                               
                    </div><!-- category-change -->

                    <!-- language-dropdown -->
                    <div class="dropdown category-dropdown language-dropdown">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="change-text">Job Location</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu category-change language-change">
                            <li><a href="#">Location 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Location 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Location 3</a></li>
                        </ul>                               
                    </div><!-- language-dropdown -->

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your key word">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div><!-- banner-form -->
```

This is the code of the **CSS**:

```
/* ==========================================================================
    banner-form
 ========================================================================== */

.banner-form {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    padding: 8px;
    max-width: 750px;
    margin: 12px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:left;
}

.banner-form form {
    border-radius:4px;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:relative;
}

.category-dropdown {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px; 
    min-width: 200px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.category-dropdown a i{
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.category-dropdown a {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-Regular', sans-serif;
}

.banner-form input {
    min-width: 375px;
    padding:0 18px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-Regular', sans-serif;
    border: none;
    margin-left: -4px;
}

.banner-form .form-control, 
.banner-form .category-dropdown {   
    display:inline-block;
    width:30%;
    height:46px;
    font-size:16px;
    color: #000;
}

.banner-form button.btn.btn-primary {
    position:absolute;
    right:-2px;
    bottom:0;
    font-size: 16px;
    max-width: 114px;
    background-color: #00a651;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0 ;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-color:#00a651;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    height:100%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.banner-form button:hover {
    background-color: #0072bc;
    border-color: #0072bc;
}

.banner-socail li {
    display: inline-block;;
}

.banner-socail li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color:transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    border-radius:3px;
}

.banner-socail li i{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.banner-socail li a:hover .fa-facebook {
    color: #405D9B;
}

.banner-socail li a:hover .fa-twitter {
    color: #29C5F6;
}

.banner-socail li a:hover .fa-google-plus {
    color: #CA3E27;
}

.banner-socail li a:hover .fa-youtube {
    color: #EB2429;
}

.category-items {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:40px 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.category a {
    color: #505050;
    display:block;
}

.banner-form .dropdown-menu {
    min-width:100%;
    padding:15px 0;
}

.category-icon {
    min-height: 37px;
    width: 100%;    
}

.category-icon img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.category-title {
    color:#505050;
}
.category-quantity {
    color: #b5b5b5;
} 

.category-title {
    display:block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.category-item:hover .category-quantity,
.category-item:hover .category-title {
    color :#00a651;
}

.ad-section {
    margin: 40px 0;
}

.ad-meta {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    min-height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:-1px;
    width:100%;
    padding-left:25px;
    display:table;
    font-size:14px;
}

.ad-meta .meta-content {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.ad-meta .meta-content .dated {
    margin-right:20px;
}

.ad-meta .meta-content .dated, 
.ad-meta .meta-content .visitors {
    font-weight:500;
    color:#9fa4a4;
}

.ad-meta .meta-content span, 
.ad-meta .meta-content a {
    font-weight:400;
    color: #9fa4a4;
}

.ad-meta .meta-content a:hover {
    color: #00a651;
}

.ad-meta .user-option a{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #9fa4a4;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
}

.featured .ad-meta .user-option a {
    width:30px;
}

.ad-meta .user-option a:hover {
    background-color:#fff;
    color: #00a651;
}

.ad-meta .user-option a.edit-item:hover {
    color:#0072bc;
}

.ad-meta .user-option a.delete-item {
    color:#ed1c24;
}

.ad-meta .user-option a.delete-item:hover {
    color:#c3171d;
}

.ad-meta a i {
    text-align: right
}

a.verified {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

a.verified i {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #00a651;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.ad-section img {
    display: inline;
}

.item-image {
    position:relative;
}

.item-image img {
    width:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.job-ad-item:hover .item-image img {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
    transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
}

.item-image-box, .item-info {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.item-image-box {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.latest-jobs-ads {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

.job-ad-item .ad-info span+a {
    color: #9fa4a4;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.job-ad-item .ad-info span {
    color: #a0a0a0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.tab-manu {
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2
}

.tab-manu h4 {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.tab-manu .nav-tabs {
    float:right;
    border: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.tab-manu .nav-tabs li a {
    padding:12px 15px;
    border-bottom:0;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    color:#9c9c9c;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

.tab-manu .nav-tabs li a:hover,
.tab-manu .nav-tabs li a:focus,
.tab-manu .nav-tabs li.active a {
    border:1px solid #f2f2f2;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    border-bottom: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #00a651;
}

.my-ads .ad-meta .pending {
    color:#f7941d;
}
```

So, what i have to edit to reach my goal?

Comment: can u explain more about what is the expected result?

Comment: @Girisha C please see https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/JaMrad, i would like to replace the dropdown menus with the textboxs.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/JaMrad

I added one rule to hide the keyword text-input field, and another to resize the job location and job category fields to half of the available space:

```
input.form-control {
    display: none !important;
}

.banner-form-full.banner-form .form-control, 
.banner-form-full.banner-form .category-dropdown {
    width: calc(50% - 40px) !important;  
    /* make width 50% of available width less the 20px left and right padding */
}
```

===

Here's another version:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/BOJJXL

**HTML**

```
<form action="#">          
 <div class="input job-category"><input type="text" name="job-category" placeholder="Job Category" ></div>

 <div class="input job-location"><input type="text" name="job-category" placeholder="Job Location" ></div>                              

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">Search</button>          
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 40px;
}

.input{
 padding:0 !important;
}

input{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  margin:0 !important;
}
.job-category{
  border-right:1px solid grey;
}

.banner-form button.btn.btn-primary{
  height:40px !important;
  right:0 !important;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  form{
    grid-template-columns:1fr; 
    grid-template-rows: 40px 40px 40px;
  }

  .job-category{
    border-right:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
  } 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: the style is correct but if you read better i need two `TEXTBOXS` instead of the `dropdown menus`. Pleaxe fix it and i will be glad to accept your answer.

Comment: Hi @Daniele, I've added an alternate suggestion above. Good luck!

Comment: Please note that both the textboxs are clickable only until at certain vertical point, please go on the right of the textbox near the end of it to see this problem. Moreover, if i would like to change the background color of the textbox the color changes only until a certain point

Comment: Hi @Daniele, I made a small change to the CSS.

Comment: Taiarora , the problem is still not fixed, there is again a little space near the end of the textbox in which you cannot click the textbox or change the color.
Please see https://codepen.io/daniele0410/pen/OozrXe .
You can see a working example here: https://translate.google.it/translate?sl=it&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=it&ie=UTF-8&u=paginebianche.it&edit-text= .

Comment: I added a few more rules to the CSS to override browser defaults and additional styling coming from your template.

Answer (score 0):

It was a minor change to the css in your codepen - https://codepen.io/girish/full/VGXzrx/

I have forked it and made few necessary updates to it, please have alook at the below-working snippet or this https://codepen.io/girish/full/VGXzrx/

I hope this what your requirement is :)

```css
.banner-form-full.banner-form .form-control,
.banner-form-full.banner-form .form-control:focus {
    width: calc(50% - 47px) !important;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 0 #e6e6e6 !important;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://demo.themeregion.com/jobs-updated/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://demo.themeregion.com/jobs-updated/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://demo.themeregion.com/jobs-updated/css/icofont.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://demo.themeregion.com/jobs-updated/css/slidr.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://demo.themeregion.com/jobs-updated/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://demo.themeregion.com/jobs-updated/css/presets/preset1.css" id="preset">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://demo.themeregion.com/jobs-updated/css/responsive.css">



<section class="job-bg page job-details-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="banner-form banner-form-full job-list-form">
      <form action="#">
        <!-- category-change -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Job Category">
        <!-- language-dropdown -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Job Location">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">Search</button> <!-- type="submit"-->
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```